# Sed performance optimization

Tags: bash, sed, io

I notice that when I use sed with the -i argument, it uses MUCH less disk read/write resources than when I redirect sed's output into a completely new file, and therefore the latter is MUCH faster (at least in my experience). Why is this?

Here are the specific commands I was using -

```
     sed -i '/\r/ s///g' file.txt <-- Slower one
     sed '/\r/ s///g' file.txt > file2.txt <-- Much faster one
```

Furthermore, I notice that when I use sed on a file that's say, ~35MB in size, it's able to process it in about ~0.3 seconds (when I redirect instead of using the -i arg). However, when I process a file that's about 7 times as large, the operation takes around ~20 seconds (once again, utilizing redirection instead of the -i arg). Why is this? Does this mean that sed works much faster on a bunch of smaller files rather than on one huge file? When I have a file that's ~25GB in size, would it be in my best interest to split the file up before processing it with sed?

Comment: Welcome to SO, please do show sample of input and sample of output with CODE TAGS in your post always.

Comment: Which `sed` implementation is this? On GNU sed, `strace` confirms that `-i` just writes to a temporary file and swaps the two, and further that it doesn't buffer so it actually ends up slower than redirection. Note that if you process any file twice with any tool, the second time will likely be a thousand times faster just because the file was in the cache.

Comment: @thatotherguy I'm using sed on Cygwin. I thought the same thing regarding caching so I tested my hypothesis with two different files and the results remained the same.

Comment: You say that `-i` uses much less disk read/write, and that redirection is therefore much faster. Did you mean that the other way around?

Comment: I meant when I look at task manager, the disk read/write MB/s values are much much lower when I use sed -i vs when I use redirection. I see how that could be misleading.

Answer (score 2):

I tested this on Linux with GNU sed 4.4, which should be similar-ish to your Cygwin. `strace -o dump sed ...` shows what's going on in each case:

With redirection, buffered output results in 2498 reads/writes for a 5MB file:

```
openat(AT_FDCWD, "file.txt", O_RDONLY)  = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=5213926, ...}) = 0
read(3, "The Project Gutenberg EBook of T"..., 4096) = 4096
fstat(1, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
read(3, "\nBook 01        Genesis\r\n\r\n01:00"..., 4096) = 4096
write(1, "The Project Gutenberg EBook of T"..., 4096) = 4096
read(3, "wn image, in the image of God\r\n "..., 4096) = 4096
write(1, "002 And the earth was without fo"..., 4096) = 4096
read(3, "cattle, and to the fowl of the a"..., 4096) = 4096
write(1, "replenish the earth, and subdue "..., 4096) = 4096
```

With `-i`, unbuffered I/O results in 115,805 reads/writes for the same file:

```
openat(AT_FDCWD, "file.txt", O_RDONLY)  = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "./sed6RccPF", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_EXCL, 0600) = 4
read(3, "The Project Gutenberg EBook of T"..., 4096) = 4096
write(4, "The Project Gutenberg EBook of T"..., 61) = 61
write(4, "of the King James Bible\n", 24) = 24  
write(4, "\n", 1)                       = 1
write(4, "Copyright laws are changing all "..., 69) = 69
write(4, "copyright laws for your country "..., 69) = 69
write(4, "this or any other Project Gutenb"..., 43) = 43 
write(4, "\n", 1)                       = 1
```

The latest git commit behaves the same way.

Until this is resolved, you'll probably want to use redirection (or better yet, a more suitable tool like `tr` in this case).

`sed` processes at the same speed regardless of file size, any difference you see there is more likely due to caching, either by the OS or the drive.

Comment: This issue [has since been fixed](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/sed.git/diff/?id=0144eeeb&id2=a847466684108d66d35c93ab9e4d7c195d6c3e55), so any GNU sed release after (but excluding) 4.5 should not have this issue.